# Which tool is proper for extracting information from ANTLR outputs?

Tags: java, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree, information-extraction

I am new to ANTLR. I parsed a grammar in antlr and got `lexer.java` and `parser.java` files. I test it with simple example and it showed proper tree in inerpreter tab and pars tree in debugger tab Now I want to extract spesific information from it. I would like to know if I need ast or not and is there any tool which is compatible with ANTLR for extracting data?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the ANTLR4 Wiki, and ANTLR-generated parser generates a parse tree data structure, and it provides a tree walker class that you can use for traversing it.  You could use this mechanism to extract information.  Note that you'd need to code a "listener" class in Java to extract the information and output it (or whatever).

For more details; see https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parse+Tree+Listeners

**UPDATE**

Since you are using ANTLR3, these links are more relevant to you:

- [Tree pattern matching](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+pattern+matching).
- [Tree Construction](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction).
- FAQ: [Tree construction](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/FAQ+-+Tree+construction).

I strongly recommend that you take the time to read the available documentation.

Comment: While the question failed to specify a version, I'm guessing this involves ANTLR 3 since the IDEs for ANTLR 4 do not include tabs named "Interpreter" and "Debugger". ANTLR 3 doesn't provide the parse tree, listener, and visitor features of ANTLR 4. Of course my recommendation for a new user would be to upgrade to ANTLR 4 before proceeding.

Comment: thanks. I have one more question if I have to work with ANTLR 3 (ANTLRWorks 1.4.3) could you please tell me your suggestion for extracting data? do I have to use AST or action code?

Comment: Sara - if you are using an older version of ANTLR that doesn't support automatic parse tree generation, etcetera, then you would need to use action code.

Comment: again one question, I got a nice parse tree in debuggaer tab, why I cannot extract data from it? whay I have to define AST? I need all information in parse tree and if I write AST, It would be completly similar to my parse tree. There is  almost not extra data or syntax in parse tree. .

Comment: Stephen-Those links were really useful, Thanks for sharing your knowledge.